# Replacing the Global Navigation Menu in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

All,  I want a menu in my SharePoint site much like CBS has one.  Where you can hover over it and it pops up a DIV across a specifc size of the screen.  Then it will show sub menus in there.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options, depending on what you would like to do:

1. Use the standard AspMenu, style level 2 <ul> elements as block elements, and use jQuery to hook up the mouseenter and mouseleave events to your level 1 <li> elements.
2. If you would like a fancy fixed-number-of-columns layout that spreads evenly across the dropdown, you need to do this either in JavaScript, or a custom UserControl that iterates through the SiteMapNode elements.